# Access to an instanced class from an other script run by first

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm trying to access to an instanced class build by firstscript.py from secondscript.py.
I run secondscript.py from firstscript.py by os.system('sudo secondscript.py') and I want access to the namespace of firstscript.py. For example I have the following code:

```
# firstscript.py
import wx
import abcd

class MyFrame(abcd):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        abcd.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

   def log(self,str_log):
        self.text_ctrl_logging.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.text_ctrl_logging.AppendText(str_log+'\n')

   def runsudo(self):
       os.system('sudo ./secondscript.py')     
    

class fghi(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = fghi(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

and the following is the secondscript.py

```
from firstscript import MyFrame
MyFrame.log("HELLO")
```

From secondscript.py I want print some string on text_ctrl_logging by log method.
But the following is the error:

```
TypeError: log() missing 1 required positional argument: 'str_log'
```

I'm sorry I'm a newbie then be patient for the stupid question.

Comment: In your second script, you are not creating a new instance of `MyFrame`, so when you call `log()` it is passing 'HELLO" as the `self` parameter. You need to create an instance of `MyFrame` for the second script to work.

Comment: Please can you point me to same link or example how to do that ?

Comment: The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) has information on how classes work. What I mentioned would be explained by "instantiation".

Comment: Thank you, sometime the only problem is find where to read and just a link is the answer.